# Angularjs directive not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started with Angularjs and I am trying to build a directive.
my js file:

```
 var app = angular.module('myCars',['ngResource']);

 app.controller('CarController', function (Post) {
        var b = Post.query(function () {
            console.log(all);
        });
        this.cars = b;
});
        app.directive("carCritics", function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl: '~/Views/Home/car-critics.cshtml'
                };
            });
```

in my cshtml file it looks like this:

```
<car-critics></car-critics>
```

I have read lots of documentations in the Internet about directives and I can´t see what I am doing wrong. Anytime I start the application the part in my directive isn´t showing. I would really appriciate any type of help.

Comment: It seems that the path in `templateUrl` param is incorrect

Comment: You need to provide more context.  The most common places I see directives fail is: when you forget to include them as a dependency of the module that is USING the directive, or if you forget to load the script that defines the directive.

Comment: @Cheruvian how would I include them as a dependency and what context is missing?

Comment: From the sounds of it we'll need your file structure, the JS controller/module code where you are using `<car-critics>`  And a larger HTML snippet from where you are using `<car-critics>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont get to straight away grab the .cshtml from the Views folder.  You must create an ActionResult and then return the "car-critics.cshtml", like so:

```
public class HomeController
    {
        public ActionResult CarCritics() {

            return View("car-critics");
        }
}
```

and directive should be:

```
app.directive("carCritics", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/Home/CarCritics'
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `templateUrl` is **incorrect**.

The `~` is something that the server knows about (e.g. using `Server.MapPath`) but the client doesn't know about (how would the client know about the server's root directory?).

You need to put the full path without the `~`.

Comment: That's due to 2 reasons: 1. That's not the full path to the view. 2. Views that sit inside the View directory are not reachable as a resource (you would need to create an action that returns the view for each view). You would want to create a different directory called StaticViews and add the view there. The path would be StaticViews/viewname.cshtml.